# Confusion about notation ; inequalities?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, notation

If I'm asked to show that

$$\begin{align*}
x_n &> z_n + y_n \\
&> z_n \\
&> y_n \\
&> z_n - y_n
\end{align*}
$$

What does it mean? Do I have to show that $x_n > z_n + y_n > z_n > y_n > z_n - y_n$? Or does each inequality involve only $x_n$ and something from the right? 
Thanks.

Comment: Absent context all we could do is to guess.

Comment: What are your $x_n, y_n$ and $z_n$?

Comment: Looks as if all quantities are being assumed positive.

Comment: It's about infimum and supremums, but the thing is, I can prove them both ways.. like I can do one inequality at a time, or I can do 'all' of them together. I'm not sure which one is the correct interpretation.